# Regex to separate email addresses from a list

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex to generate a list of strings from the list of e-mail addresses.

```
var emailAddress = "joe@sad.com; joe@happy.com; joe@elated.com";
```

want to create a List of strings

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>();
```

contains

```
email[0] = joe@sad.com
email[1] = joe@happy.com
email[2] = joe@elated.com
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex instead of just `String.Split()` to put it into an array? Have you made any effort to write such a regular expression yourself?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: As Ken mentions above, why not use `String.Split()` with a delimiter of some type?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex for that!

```
var emailAddress = "joe@sad.com; joe@happy.com; joe@elated.com";

var emails = emailAddress.Split(';').Select(i => i.Trim()).ToList();
```

Or, if you don't want to have to trim:

```
var emails = emailAddress.Split(new[]{' ',';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string emailAddress = "joe@sad.com; joe@happy.com; joe@elated.com";
 string[] emails = emailAddress.Replace(" ", "").Split(';'); // this will put every email in one position

foreach(string email in emails){
// your code for every email
}
```

your string emails will be an array of strings with positions you can also do a normal for cicle with i=0; i< ... etc

Hope it help :)

Answer (score -1):

Consider the Following Code...

```
var emailAddress = "joe@sad.com; joe@happy.com; joe@elated.com";
List<string> emails = new List<string>();
emails = Regex.Matches(emailAddress, @"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Good Luck!

Comment: -1. Why complicate things by matching the email addresses? What if your regex for that isn't complete?